# How do I ignore paths containing asterisks with IgnoreRoute (or map them to a static resource)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

For complicated reasons I won't go into, we have some requests that come into our application for `/blah/[**Token**]` (this is literal, none of this is placeholders).

Currently we get errors from MVC saying it can't find an IController for this every time the request comes in.

We would like the request to either: a) 404 or b) serve up a static placeholder image.

Try as we might, we can't figure out how to escape these characters in an IgnoreRoute/Route call such that they are treated literally. Eg. we've tried:

```
IgnoreRoute("blah/\[\*\*Token\*\*\]")
IgnoreRoute("blah/[\*\*Token\*\*]")
```

But the problem still persists.

How do we escape this path, such that actual requests to `blah/[**Token**]` are ignored and result in 404 (or alternatively, how do we map this exact path to a static image)?

Note: We have edited web.config so that * is not a disallowed character. We can't (currently) easily change this incoming request path, we just want to stop our error logs filling up when it happens :-)

Comment: Have you tried URL encoding your chars? %2A for * and %5B %5C for []?  IgnoreRoute("blah/%5B%2A%2AToken%2A%2A%5C")

Comment: Have you tried using an `IRouteConstraint` rather than a Regex string? It's [much quicker](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/10/13/optimising-asp-net-mvc3-routing) and easier to isolate for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a route constraint like this

```
IgnoreRoute("{*constraint}", new { constraint = @".*\[\*\*ProductImageFile\*\*]" });
```